# What's the simplest way to edit conflicted files in one go when using git and an editor like Vim or textmate?

Tags: git, editor, conflict

I'm trying to tweak a little

When I type in git status on the commandline, I get a list of files that need to be resolved like so:

```
# Unmerged paths: #
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      apache2/templates/default/apache2.conf.erb
#   both modified:      bootstrap/attributes/default.rb
#   both modified:      iptables/metadata.rb
#   both modified:      kickstart/templates/default/ks.cfg.erb
#   both modified:      openssl/metadata.json
#   both modified:      postfix/metadata.json
#   both modified:      postfix/templates/default/main.cf.erb
```

Is there a simple way to pass this list of file paths into a text editor, so you can edit them all in one go?

I can get to this for example, by simply piping it through grep:

```
[17:37]:git status | grep "both modified"
#   both modified:      apache2/templates/default/apache2.conf.erb
#   both modified:      bootstrap/attributes/default.rb
#   both modified:      iptables/metadata.rb
#   both modified:      kickstart/templates/default/ks.cfg.erb
#   both modified:      openssl/metadata.json
#   both modified:      postfix/metadata.json
#   both modified:      postfix/templates/default/main.cf.erb
```

But I'm not sure how to return this using just shell commands, or whether it's simplest to drop into ruby or python, to pass each line through a regexp, to filter out the `#   both modified:`.

The end result I want is something like this:

```
vim #{space_separated_list_of_files}
```

How would you guys do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a pair of aliases I have in my gitconfig, taken from the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Editing.2Fadding_conflicted_files):

```
edit-unmerged = \
    "!f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u ; }; vim `f`"
add-unmerged = \
    "!f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u ; }; git add `f`"
```

Should do what you want!

Comment: I think this is really helpful and awesome.  However, it doesn't handle spaces properly.  Here's a version that I (eventually) came up with that doesn't break from encountering files with spaces in their names: `!f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u | sed -r 's/ /\\\\ /g' ; }; f | xargs vim`

Comment: @Destin There are just so many things that will break if you have spaces in filenames; if you control the project I'd suggest just not putting spaces in filenames in the first place.

Comment: @Jefromi: you mean that there are so many programs that can't handle spaces in filenames, so we have to work around it by avoiding spaces.

Comment: @Destin: that doesn't work on msysgit/Git for Windows.

Comment: To open these from within vim, (because I start Neovim on windows without the commandline). I use `:execute 'args ' . system('git unmerged | paste -sd \" \" -')`. My unmerged command is as in Destin's comment, but without piping to vim, so it outputs the files on seperate lines. The paste -sd part puts the files onto one line for the args command. (or you could use tabe)

Answer (score 3):

Shortest I can think of:

```
vim `git status|grep 'both modified'|cut -d: -f2`
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the git mergetool command ? That doesn't open all the files in one go, but iterate on all needed files, which might be only what you need. You can even use vim to do the merge

> git mergetool --tool=vimdiff